# Connection to Mysql server database failed on google VM machine

Tags: mysql, mysqli, database-connection, google-cloud-platform, mysql-error-1064

I made a google cloud VM instance where I installed mysql and then configured a db, 
when I try to access this database from my own computer it failed to connect with this error :

```
mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

I tired creating firewall suggested in [link](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mysql-remote-access#install_mysql_server)

```
<?php
//phpinfo();
echo 'start'. date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
define('DBM_HOST', '<vm_external_ip_add>');
//define('DBM_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DBM_USERNAME', 'user');
define('DBM_PASSWORD', 'pass');
define('DBM_DATABASE', 'db');
$link =  mysql_connect(DBM_HOST, DBM_USERNAME, DBM_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());var_dump($link);if ($link) {
    echo 'connected to ' .DBM_HOST;
}
```

I don't want to use cloud sql , i want to connect to this virtual machine

I used terminal command :

```
mysql -uuser -p -h1<vm_ip_address>
```

Nothing works.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: check to make sure skip-networking is commented out.  Also, make sure that the 'username'@'%-or-correct-client-ip' is granted access.  Kind of sounds like skip-networking.  If bind-address is set, comment that line as well.